# Is toString() mandatory while accessing the individual element of a JSON object in Java

Tags: java, json

I am quite new to Java and trying to understand the effect of using `toString()` while accessing the individual `string` elements of JSON object in Java.

Below are the steps followed:

1. Parse the JSON data. Let's assume only string elements are there in parsed JSON data.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(json_data);
```

```
{
   "firstname" : "new",
   "lastname" : "human",
   "id" : "some_id"
}
```

2. Try to access the individual elements.
   Access without `toString()`:
   `Public static String firstname = jsonObj.get("firstname");`
   Access with `toString()`:
   `Public static String firstname = jsonObj.get("firstname").toString();`

I do not see a difference when I try to print the data.
However I would like to know the difference between the above 2 methods, and also will there be any issues if I use without `toString()` in this particular case.

Appreciate your help.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have some Int or other type of data type variables in your model class and you want to parse it into a string so for that we use toString(), it will convert int or any other data variable into a string, in your case here you already have string so no need to change again and again and JSON uses string variables when it comes from backend so that the purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now I understood why it is not required for strings.

Answer (score 1):

`toString()` returns string representation of property/object on which this method is called.
Whenever we print an object reference, it invokes the `toString()` method internally as a result , it is not making difference.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using Json, there is no difference.
You can use the Option, you like more